# Convert Array of parameters in assoc To Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

i have a table in mysql database that contains all parameters of the website:

```
  Param  |  Value
Myparam1 |   2
Myparam2 |   myvalue
```

I launch a query on this table to get all parameters in a associative array.
I get this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'parametre' => string 'Myparam1' (length=8)
      'valeur' => string '2' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'parametre' => string 'Myparam2' (length=8)
      'valeur' => string 'myvalue' (length=7)
```

But i would like this:

```
'Myparam1' => 2
'Myparam2' => 'myvalue'
```

How to get that please?

Comment: Did you try anything, or are you using SO to get free programming services?

Comment: did you see that i posted some sample code, that means i tried somethings. Is there a problem Barmar?

Comment: There's no code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach to rearrange the array:

```
$array_out = array();
foreach($array_from_db as $a){
    $array_out[$a['parametre']] = $a['valeur'];
}
print_r($array_out);
```

Comment: Great you're the best.